# (OS X) Programmatically bound NSTableView does not display values

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nstableview, nsmanagedobject

I created a viewController with a tableView and set the identifier of the only column to "name". Then I created an arrayController, bound it to a `NSManagedObjectContext` and set the right entity name.

When I now load the viewController, the tableView does display the correct amount of row. But unfortunately the cells do not contain the value of the `NSManagedObject`s value for the key `name`.

What do I have to implement in my `NSManagedObject` subclass or in the viewController (which is the tableViews viewController)?

I'd like to show you some code, but I don't know what could be helpful here, because it's more an conceptional question... So I'll post code as requested in comments.

**UPDATE**

This is the code I'm using to bind the arrayController tho the tableView:

```
[_tableView bind:NSContentBinding toObject:_arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name" options:nil];
```

To inspect what the tableView gets, I added this line (after adding property called "content"):

```
[self bind:NSContentBinding toObject:_arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.name" options:nil];
```

In the setter I got an array containing `NSString` instances. But the tableView still does not display any values...

Comment: Is this a view-based table view? What does the cell view consist of? Is it a bare `NSTextField`? Is it an `NSTableCellView` that contains subviews? If so, is its `textField` outlet connected to an appropriate subview? Is it a custom view?

Comment: Now. It's a cell-based tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the standard `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [[_arrayController arrangedObjects] count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return [[[_arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:[tableColumn identifier]];
}
```

I think this is a solid solution, though. I might became obsessed by the `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` idea.

Comment: Using the data source methods is fine. Bindings are not always the best technology. For an `NSCell`-based table view, you typically bind the table **column(s)** and the table view itself sets its own bindings based on the bindings of the columns. (You can also bind the table view yourself, in addition to the columns, which allows you to override or disable some of the automatic behaviors.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. Great, this clarifies many questions.